# request to one IP and reply from other IP on same machine

Tags: linux, nic, tftp

I have a topology where my machine sends tftp traffic to tftp server[linux machine] on one IP address and receives reply from another IP address [2 NIC on tftp server] and there after uses second IP address for entire transfer. but i want to know how can i configure this rule[on tftp server] that when it replies it should be from ***second*** IP address.

what kind of rules do I need to configure is it IP tables? please assume the routes are configured on linux machine.

Answer (score 1):

nothing to do with iptables...
I do not know why you have set up an scenario like yours but a regular TFTP server receiving a request on one IP is going to answer on the same IP, otherwise you need a custom coded TFTP server...